# How can I mask or convert Int32 to Int16 in swift

Tags: swift, int, bitmask

**Data loss is no problem for me.**

```
var temp1:Int32 = 45058 
var temp2:Int32 = -20345 
var temp3:Int32 = -40345

var temp4:Int16 =  Int16(temp1)//overflow
var temp5:Int16 =  Int16(temp2)//return wrog value
var temp6:Int16 =  Int16(temp3)//overflow
```

Also tried this, but it is also returning wrong value, it is not what I want.

```
temp4 = Int16(temp1 & 0x0000ffff)//overflow
```

In my C code, there is no any issue because c compiler does this by self.

Comment: How do you intend to turn `45058` into a signed 16 bit integer, if max value for signed 16 bit integer is `32767`?

Comment: @mag_zbc This is obviously supposed to be truncating cast which is what would happen in C or Java.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually very simple, you just have to say explicitly what you want to do:

```
var temp4: Int16 =  Int16(truncatingIfNeeded: temp1) // -20478
var temp5: Int16 =  Int16(truncatingIfNeeded: temp2) // -20345
var temp6: Int16 =  Int16(truncatingIfNeeded: temp3) // 25191
```

(the method is called `truncatingBitPattern:` in Swift 3)

`truncatingIfNeeded` will reinterpret the lower 16 bits as `Int16`.

Note that `& 0xffff` won't work in this case. The default initializer is trying to **convert the numeric value**, not the bit value and unfortunately `45058`, or `0xB002` will be unchanged through `& 0xffff` and it won't fit `Int16`. That would work for unsigned integers though.

Comment: Can you add the resulting values and one or two sentences explaining why those values are achieved?